# converting selected value from dropdownlist into int

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a drop down list and I want the selected value to put into an int variable, then in my aspx page I want to assign it to a rowspan. This is my C# code for getting the value and converting it:

```
protected void drop_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int a = Int32.Parse(drop.SelectedValue.ToString());
```

And this is my aspx code where I'm trying to assign the variable a :

```
 <asp:TableHeaderRow>
 <asp:TableHeaderCell RowSpan="<% a %>">Hostese</asp:TableHeaderCell>
 </asp:TableHeaderRow>
```

I get the error: cannot create an object of type int32 from its string representation. Can anyone say why? It's an asp.net application with C#.

Comment: What do you get for drop.SelectedValue, are you sure it is an integer?

Comment: Did you try this int a = Int32.Parse(drop.SelectedValue.Trim());

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try setting this value when you read dropdown value.

```
<asp:TableHeaderRow>
    <asp:TableHeaderCell ID="h1" >Hostese</asp:TableHeaderCell>
</asp:TableHeaderRow> 



protected void drop_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    h1.RowSpan = Int32.Parse(drop.SelectedValue.ToString());
```

Comment: it doesn't give me an error but it doesn't bring me how i want..let's say i select 3 than the rowspan is only on 2 and the 3rd is brought near the second

Comment: did you checked the html source?

Comment: yes...the 3rd is brought near the second..1 and 2 are displayed correct.

Comment: did you see rowspan on th element?

Comment: yes..when I choose 1 it brings me the row under the rowheader and when i select 2, one is brought near and one under..

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
int a = int.TryParse(drop.SelectedValue, out a)? a : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

If value of `drop.SelectedValue` isn't `int` then you will get this error. For example if the value contains a floating point.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `int.Parse(drop.SelectedValue)` or `int.Parse(drop.SelectedValue.Trim())` instead of `Int32.Parse(drop.SelectedValue.ToString())`. `drop.SelectedValue` is already in string format so you need not convert it using `ToString`

Answer (score 0):

Try `Int32.TryParse` method, which try to convert string representation to int without throwing an exception. Also check the values of your drop down list items. This exception occurs when string value does not represent integer value.

Answer (score 0):

if dropdown list items value is in numbers(digits) like...

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
         <asp:ListItem Text="Please Select" Value="-1"></asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Text="1st" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Text="2nd" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Text="3rd" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
     </asp:DropDownList>
```

then you can simply do this...

```
int i = Int32.Parse(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
```

This always works for me!!!!!!!!!!